# Need Help Condensing This Logarithmic Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm taking pre-calculus and usually don't have trouble condensing logs with the log properties but the exponents in this one are causing me to flounder. If someone could give me a line-by-line run through with emphasis on the exponent rules and how they end up combining I'd be really grateful.

Problem

$$\frac{-2}{3}\log_5(5m^2)+\frac1 2 \log_5(25m^2)$$

Comment: Don’t you suppose that OP meant $\log_5$?

Comment: yeah I did. New to mathstack so wasn't sure as how to format.

Comment: @CharlesNicholson You can hit the "edit" button to see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

For each logarithm, start using the fact that $\log(ab^2)=\log(a)+2\log(b)$ and simplify as much as you can (remembering that $\log_a(a)=1$, $\log_a(a^2)=2$).

I am sure that you can easily take from here.